# How to block a suspend function that is calling firebase

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, firebase-authentication

In my `AuthRepository` I'm trying to make a `login` function that will run asynchronously in the main thread, I'm using firebase auth to do so and a `sealed class AuthResult` to handle the result state.

My problem is that when I try to return the `AuthResult` state it will be null because I return the `var authResult: AuthResult = null` variable before the `.addOnCompleteListener` is finished...

Here is my function:

```kotlin
override suspend fun login(email: String, password: String): AuthResult {
    return try {
        var authResult: AuthResult? = null

        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    task.result.user?.let {
                        authResult = AuthResult.Success(it)
                    }
                } else {
                    // exception
                    authResult = AuthResult.Error(message = "An error occurred", task.exception)
                }
            }

        authResult ?: AuthResult.Error(message = "An error occurred null")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        AuthResult.Error("An error has occurred", e)
    }

}
```

I call this function using invoke usecase in my `LoginViewModel`:

```kotlin
private val _state = MutableStateFlow<AuthResult?>(null)
val state: StateFlow<AuthResult?> = _state

fun login(email: String, password: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        _state.value = loginUseCase(email, password)
    }
}
```

so considering my problem `state` will be:

```kotlin
AuthResult.Error(message = "An error occurred null")
```

what im trying to accomplish is blocking the `suspend fun login(...)` until `.addOnCompleteListener{}` is finished...

Comment: Just use `await()` instead of `addOnCompleteListener()`.

Comment: If you want to try using Jetpack Compose, then I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8) will help.

Comment: @AlexMamo Alex, when I built my app I decided to change the ```startDestination``` in the ```NavHost``` in ```MainActivity``` rather than in the UI Screens causing NavHost to recompose when currentUser changes, then in ```onDestroy``` remove the auth listener. 
Is injecting it as Flow better? and removing this logic from MainActivity?

Comment: @EmekCohen Yes, using Flow is much better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Was missing a dependency so I couldn't use `await()`:

add this:

```kotlin
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.0'
```

then add `.await()` after `.addOnCompleteListener {}`:

```kotlin
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        ...
    }.await()
```

Comment: I can't verify this right now, but do you need this `addOnCompleteListener()`? I think it is redundant if you use `await()`.

Comment: @broot that's correct, however if I do ```val task = firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()``` then ```task.exception``` will throw ```unresolved reference: unkown```